# How verify if node "ssh" is reachable or not ? (connected or disconnected)

Tags: networking, ssh

I have this list of ip address:

```
172.16.65.74
172.16.65.75
172.16.65.76
172.16.65.77
```

I have on each host a file named "replicas.txt" (the same file on all hosts).
My goal is to get one copy of these replicas files.

I'd like to verify 172.16.65.74 if it is reachable or not, if it is disconnected, i test the second machine 172.16.65.75, if its connected, i copy the file replicas.txt the current host i work on.

Is that possible ?

Thank you.
Bests.

Comment: Since ssh is set to port 22, you can at least test if that port is reachable at any given IP address. See this Server Fault article for more information. http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

You can then use a bash script to run any given command depending on the output of the commands in that article. Is that what you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a very basic bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mymachines=(172.16.65.74 172.16.65.75 172.16.65.76 172.16.65.77)

for machine in "${mymachines[@]}"; do
  echo "Trying to access $machine ..."
  if `scp -o ConnectTimeout=5 yourlogin@$machine:/path/to/my/file ./`; then
     echo "Succeeded."
     break;
  else
     echo "Failed, trying next if available..."
  fi
done
```

This will pick up hosts one by one and try to copy that remote file to your local filesystem. If any of them succeeds, then it exits; otherwise, it will continue the loop to the next available machine.